# Add box around text for Excel to Powerpoint VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, outline

I am importing data from Excel into Powerpoint slides. How would I be able to add a box/outline around the textframe? Also is there any way in which I can add a static outline that does not move, even if I have no text in the cell I am importing from?

Thank you for any and all help!

Here's snippet of my code:

```
Set ppSlide2 = ppPres.Slides.Add(i + 1, ppLayoutBlank).Shapes
Set HeaderPPT = ppSlide2.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 75, 150, 800, 700).TextFrame.TextRange
If Sheet1.Range("P" & RowExcel).Text = "Title" Then          
            With HeaderPPT
                .Text = vbNewLine & Cells(RowExcel, col + 9)
                .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.Name = "Calibri Light"
                .Font.Size = 55
            End With
End If
```

Comment: It may not help, but when I displayed data and charts from Excel in Powerpoint slides, I usually copy them into Paint first and then copy and paste the image into the slide. This pastes it as an actual image rather than an embedded Excel object that bloats my presentation.

Comment: @Martin Parkin I have a macro that takes data from over 200 rows of Excel data and updates it into Powerpoint so I won't be able to copy and paste images, unfortunately. Thank you though!! :)

Answer (score 0):

TextFrame or TextRange doesn't have the border element.
The parent 'Shape' can have borders like this.

```
Dim sld as Slide, shp as Shape
Set sld = Activepresentation.Slides(1)
Set shp = sld.Shapes.AddShapes(msoShapeRectangle, 100,100,100,100)
With shp
    .Line.Visible = True
    .Line.Weight = 2
    .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255,0,0)
End with
```

To put a static border, I think you can add a rectangle or TextBox first.
And then add a TextBox again with Excel cell contents.
(But if you add a Textbox with AddTextBox, the shape's border is static by default even if it has no text in it.)

Any way, I tested the following code:

```
Set ppSlide2 = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count, ppLayoutBlank).Shapes

'first, add a box(rectangle) or textbox so that the z-order can be lower than the next Textbox
Set HeaderBOX = ppSlide2.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 75, 150, 800, 700)
'or Set HeaderBOX = ppSlide2.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 75, 150, 800, 700)
With HeaderBOX
    .Name = "HeaderBOX"
    .Fill.Visible = False   'make it transparent
    .Line.Visible = True
    .Line.ForeColor.RGB = rgbBlack 'RGB(0,0,0)
    .Line.Weight = 2
End With

'then, add a textbox
Set HeaderPPT = ppSlide2.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 75, 150, 800, 700).TextFrame.TextRange
With HeaderPPT
    .Text = vbNewLine & "Excel Cell Text Here"
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Name = "Calibri Light"
    .Font.Size = 55
End With
```